# MyClass::class - get string representation of MyClass

Tags: php

The double colon (::) is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

This is used to access protected methods and properties (and constants).

However, I have seen the use of ::class to return the string representation of the class. Like so:

```
namespace App;
class MyClass
{

}

var_dump(MyClass::class); # string(11) "App\MyClass"
```

I have searched far and wide for a documentation over this behaviour.

Is the above code also using the Scope Resolution Operator or is this something completely different? If so, what is the name of it?

If it is using the SRO, does that mean that PHP places a static property "class" behind the scenes? (I have been unable to override this static property though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature in PHP5.5, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

It's basically for getting the full class name. It's also not a static variable (see no preceding $) but a language feature using the class keyword. As per the note on php.net:

> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time transformation. That means at the time the class name string is created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The operator ::class was introduced with [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.new-features.php) and returns a string with the fully qualified class name.